# Help Needed with Counting Votes for Candidates A and B

Tags: probability, combinatorics, problem-solving

I have a math question that's been boggling my mind, and I'm hoping someone can help me out. Here's the scenario:

> The candidates A and B are the finalist for an award. A committee of
> 14 members will place their vote (in favour of one of the candidates)
> into a ballot box. Suppose that A receives 9 votes and B receives 5.
> In how many ways the ballot can be selected, one at a time, from the
> ballot box so that there are always more votes in favour of A. Explain
> your solution and print all such ways in Mathematica.

I attempted to solve this problem using [Bertrand's Ballot Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem), which states that the probability of A being strictly ahead of B throughout the count is given by $\frac{p-q}{p+q}$, where $p$ is the number of votes for A and $q$ is the number of votes for B. In our case, this would be $\frac{9-5}{9+5} = \frac{4}{14}$. But what next?

However, I'm struggling to figure out how many ways we can select a ballot, one at a time, from the ballot box, while maintaining the condition that A always has more votes than B in each selection. I'm not sure if the probability I calculated using Bertrand's theorem applies directly to counting the ways to select the ballots.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me solve this problem and, if possible, provide all the ways these ballots can be selected while meeting the condition mentioned above. Please explain your solution clearly so that I can understand the process.

Comment: Bertrand's ballot theorem is the hard part. How many ways in total are there to draw all the ballots, ignoring the constraint?

Comment: Without considering the constraint, is it 14! ways?

Comment: Yes, and those ways are all equally likely. So by Bertrand's ballot theorem...

Comment: I don't understand the hint sorry.

Comment: Say there are 100 equally likely outcomes of an experiment and you know the probability of meeting some condition is 3/4. Then how many outcomes meet the condition?

Comment: @Karl 75

So, in my case, it'd be 4/14 * 14!?

Input
$$
14 ! \times \frac{4}{14}
$$
Exact result
$$
24908083200
$$

Comment: @Karl Don't you think that answer is a little too large? For example, how do I "print all such ways" in Mathematica, my computer would most likely crash.

Comment: Maybe the intent is for you to treat the voters as indistinguishable, so you'd just print (and count) the possible strings of As and Bs that satisfy the requirement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148499/discussion-between-bryan-c-and-karl).